# CRM 2015 Outlook Plugin error

Tags: outlook, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I am getting the following when trying to install the CRM 2015 plugin for Outlook:

[image]

I have Outlook 2010 32 bit version installed and I downloaded the 32 bit version of the CRM 2015 Outlook plugin.
thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by a duplication of ID's in the Sitemap as documented in this blog post:

[UNABLE TO CONFIGURE OUTLOOK CLIENT AFTER UPGRADE TO CRM 2015](http://www.tylersand.com/?p=38)

Answer (score -1):

Did you have a chance to read first three sentences?

It looks like the add-in could connect to the CRM server. Try to contact your system administrator as the error message states.

Comment: I did read the first three sentences. This happens after the configuration wizard connects to the CRM server. 

I get the feeling this issue is to do with the way the Sitemap is laid out going on the line "An item with the same key has already been added". I think the Outlook client is trying to build a navigation pane of its own based on the Sitemap but because a key already exists it is having trouble.